# Oracle Programming Query to split data from One table into two

Tags: sql, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table which has got a field which has many "Item numbers" (starting from 8%, 2%, etc...). These Item numbers have further components, which are also stored in the very same column (because each component is also an Item). Now the requirement is to if I encounter an Item number that has its component number starting from 8%, then I need to create a new column against the Main Item number (some thing which is called 800-Level Items) and store it there, and if the main Item Number has 2% component number then i should put it into yet another column something like (200-Level).

```
                      Field1  XLike YLike
                      ---------------------
(Main Item)            XXXX       
(Main Item's component)YYYY
(Main Item's component)ZZZZ
(Main Item's component)XABC
(Main Item's component)YABC
```

Now depending upon the starting character of the Sting in Field1, I need to segregate the values in fields XLike and YLike in following manner:

```
       Field1 XLike           YLike
        -------------------------
        XXXX   XABC            YYYY, YABC
        YYYY   
        ZZZZ
        XABC
        YABC
```

Comment: Can you provide some real data? You're talking about 8% and 2% "item numbers" and sample data is characters. Also... how to distinguish main items from components since row order is not something to rely on?

Comment: Please consider the sample data that I have provided to be items of number datatype(Please use imagination, to imagine them starting from 2 and 8 resp.). Also the data structure is complex as it involves many more tables..i have simplified it the above example....please consider the given situation only, rest can be managed in back end, do not worry about them

Comment: Ok... if we put slight datatype inconsistency aside, can you tell how to distinguish main items from components? How to tell whether YYYY is a main item or a component, AND how to tell that eg. YABC is subcomponent of the item XXXX?